# Ubuntu Jaunty Video Problems

Tags: ubuntu, video

Recently I upgraded my machine to Ubuntu Jaunty(9.04), and believe me its superb. The boot time is pretty less, everything seems to work perfectly. Except the video. I am unable to play any video file in any player. I am using Intel 845GLAD motherboard(integrated Graphics card).

> $> lspci -nn | grep VGA
>
> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller
>   [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile
>   945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express
>   Integrated Graphics Controller
>   [8086:27a2] (rev 03)

And I searched over the internet to find out, whether its just me or anybody else is also facing the same problem. Yes there are many. So I tried the popular solution:https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReinhardTartler/X/RevertingIntelDriverTo2.4. Then the video starts getting played, compiz effects seem to work properly. But suddenly rendering was not getting done properly. Many horizontal lines were getting displayed on my screen, So I moved back to latest intel video driver. How do I get my video working on Jaunty?

Update:One more reason why I dont want to roll back to previous version of Intel driver is, the Multiple Monitor support. Its pretty good and seamless in Jaunty(with the default/latest intel driver), but not the same in Previous version. Please help me.

Update: I want a solution other than upgrading my kernel to 2.6.30.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have another hard drive, or partition of a hard drive, to test a clean install of 9.04?

I found that networking and video on behaved quite badly after an upgrade, but after clean install, the problems went away. In particular, my network interface configured with ndiswrapper did not want to work after upgrade, but after clean install, network worked better than before.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at /etc/X11/xorg.conf, in the section that says

```
Section "Device"
    ...
EndSection
```

Make sure that you have

```
Driver "intel"
```

in that section. I had similar problems with my intel card, but after that, everything worked fine. (Of course you will have to restart X).

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to try - create a new user, and see if that user still has the problem.  I've found sometimes when upgrading (I keep my home directory on a 2nd HDD) that there are leftovers in .dirs that can cause problems.  A new, clean user probably won't have that cruft.